# Get day from date, Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

I haven´t found much searching on the net.

The case: 
One cell is filled out in date-format by the TODAY() function. How can I update another cell with the actual day as string? I´ve seen older examples by using CHOOSE func, or the the WEEKDAY() func formatted. Nothing seems to work for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing seems to work for me"? Do you get an error message?

Comment: What have you tried that doesn't work? If you don't mention that, you're likely to get answers that suggest exactly that.

Comment: Like the provided answer down here, as read on another site, that formel gives me an parser error.

Comment: Are you using a language other than English? If so, then you need to use semi-colons instead of commas in your functions. That may be the source of your error.

Comment: English is default. Its fixed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
=TEXT(A1;"dddd")
```

where A1 is the cell with the date.

Comment: Funny: [Google examples have a comma separating the fields](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139?hl=en), but it doesn't work. Using semicolon as in the answer works.

Comment: @Diego It probably has to do with your spreadsheet locale settings. It should work with comma in US locale.

Comment: [you are correct](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/how-to-change-a-non-regional-google-sheets-formula/#How_Google_Sheets_Language_and_Locale_Settings_Affect_Functions). Anyway I found it odd that it does, bad design.

Answer (score 4):

This solution works for me:

`=CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(A1),"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday")`

where A1 is the cell with the date.